# Implementing a unique UITableView cell before prototype cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, uitableview

A good example of what I mean is the "Me" tab in the twitter iOS app.  It displays the users profile information, but then below that it displays all of the users tweets in a UITableView.  When you scroll down to view all the tweets, the profile information scrolls away too.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not a table view cell, but rather `UITableView`'s [`tableHeaderView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.